# Is there any splitting theorem for compact manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

One of the important results in Riemannian geometry is the [Cheeger and Gromoll splitting theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_theorem). It states that if a complete manifold of nonnegative Ricci curvature admits a line then it is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^k\times N$.

I wonder is there any splitting (tori decomposition or any) theorem for compact manifolds? any reference?

IMHO one possible statement could be something like the following:

If a **compact** Riemannian manifold of nonnegative Ricci curvature satisfys in "A" then it is homeomorphic to $N\# \Bbb T^m$ or  $N \times  \Bbb T^k$ or  $N \times \Bbb S^k$.

**P.S.** I am interested in compact manifolds of nonnegative Ricci/sectional curvature.

Comment: If you are asking if $M$ is isometric to a product, then it's no and an example is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/522563/629362)

Comment: A possibly easy way to do this is to figure out what assumptions imply that a geodesic on the compact manifold lifts to a line in the universal cover and apply Cheeger-Gromoll.

Comment: @ArcticChar: I am asking if M is homeomorphic to product. is this same as that?